# Zustand not rerendering once token is set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, token, zustand

TLDR: I could be doing this wrong, but I had this working with Redux but after switching to Zustand I can't figure this out. After logging in and confirming with devtools, a token is set. Yet Zustand is not rerendering the component. So after logging in I'm directed to my home component but no data is shown (all fetches fail due to no token). If I refresh the page, all is good.

The issue is my "apiClient" uses the token, but seems like the token isn't getting updated before use.

Store:

```
let token = localStorage.getItem("token");

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiURL,
  headers: {
    "...etc, Token=${token}`,
  },
});
```

I need apiClient in the store.js to pass to my slices, for example:

```
const useStore = create(
  devtools((set, get) => ({
    auth: authSlice(set, get, apiClient),
    views: viewsSlice(set, get, apiClient),
  }))
);
```

It would make sense to be able to get the state of the token rather than localStorage, but I can't use get() outside a slice in the store. What would be a better approach?

Comment: If your store the token in your app state, you can access the token by useStore hook in your component. Something like token = useStore(state=>state.token)

Comment: @Peter That's what I have in App.js but it's not rerendering.

```const token = useStore((state) => state.auth.token);

  const protectedViews = () => {
    return token === localStorage.getItem("token") ||
      localStorage.getItem("token") === !undefined ? (
      <MainLayout />
    ) : (
      <Auth />
    );
  };```


And then I call the protectedViews function in the return. Which works and shows MainLayout but token is undefined till refresh.